# Is there a method to setup flink memory dynamically?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, flink-batch

When using Apache Flink we can configure values in **flink-conf.yaml**. But here using CLI commands we can assign some values Dynamically when **starting or submitting a job or a task** in flink.

```
eg:- bin/taskmanager.sh start-foreground -Dtaskmanager.numberOfSlots=12
```

But some values like **jobmanager.memory.process.size and taskmanager.memory.process.size** are unable to set Dynamically using "-D".

*Is there a way to set up those values dynamically when starting jobmanager and taskmanager using CLI?*

Comment: were you able to set the properties dynamically ? If yes, what was the solution implemented by you ?

Comment: @mandar when we start jobmanager by CLI we should pass those properties as arguments. But the issue is we cannot do it in current flink versions as it was not implemented in flink yet. They plan to send it in next version

Answer (score 0):

May be this might help you :

```
ParameterTool parameters = ParameterTool.fromPropertiesFile("src/main/resources/application.properties"); // one can specify the properties defined in conf/flink-conf.yaml in this properties file
Configuration config = Configuration.fromMap(parameters.toMap());
TaskExecutorResourceUtils.adjustForLocalExecution(config);

StreamExecutionEnvironment env =
        StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment(config);
env.setParallelism(3);

System.out.println("Config Params : " + config.toMap());
```

Make a note to set the parallelism equal to the number of task slots for task manager as per [this](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/concepts/flink-architecture/#task-slots-and-resources) link. By default, the number of task slots for a task manager is one.